# histogram equalization on color image in YCbCr space

Tags: image-processing, colors, color-space

Edit. I found the reason. I didn't do the clamping, which  I thought I did.

I am trying to implement histogram equalization on an RGB color image.
I understand that the equalization should be done to the luminance channel only, therefore here is what I am doing:

1. convert R,G,B to Y, Cb, Cr by using the following conversion:
   [image]
   note the ranges of Y, Cb, Cr are all [0...255]
2. generate the grayscale (Y channel) mapping (i.e, old_Y to new_Y) table by computing the histogram and the CDF
3. for every pixel with value (old_Y, old_Cb, old_Cr), replace it with:
        (new_Y, old_Cb, old_Cr)
4. convert (new_Y, old_Cb, old_Cr) to (new_R, new_G, new_B) by doing the following:
   [image]
5. display the image.

Here is what I get for the result:

[image]

Any idea about the saturated regions? Am I missing something in doing the color conversion?

Comment: Have you tried any kind of existing implementations for both conversion and equalization? If yes, does the results differ from yours?

Comment: Thank you. I found the reason. It was because I didn't do the clamping, which I thought I did.